# Why should I use Integers when I could just use floats or doubles in C#?

Tags: c#, integer

Just learning C# at the moment.

I don't get why anyone would use Integers when they could use floats or doubles..

Floats will add/subtract whole numbers AND decimal numbers so why would anyone ever bother using a plain old integer?

Seems like floats or double will take care of anything that an Integer can do with the bonus of being able to handle . numbers too..

Thanks!

Comment: You have a *lot* to learn about the downsides of floating point! Start with the classic [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetict](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: Calculations with integers are faster than with floating point numbers.

Answer (score 13):

The main reason is the same reason we often prefer to use integer fractions instead of fixed-precision decimals. With rational fractions, (1/3) times 3 is always 1. (1/3) plus (2/3) is always 1. (1/3) times 2 is (2/3).

Why? Because integer fractions are exact, just like integers are exact.

But with fixed-precision real numbers -- it's not so pretty. If (1/3) is `.33333`, then 3 times (1/3) will not be 1. And if (2/3) is `.66666`, then (1/3)+(2/3) will not be one. But if (2/3) is `.66667`, then (1/3) times 2 will not be (2/3) and 1 minus (1/3) will not be (2/3).

And, of course, you can't fix this by using more places. No number of decimal digits will allow you to represent (1/3) exactly.

Floating point is a fixed-precision real format, much like my fixed-precision decimals above. It doesn't always follow the naive rules you might expect. See the classic paper [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

To answer your question, to a first approximation, you should use integers whenever you possibly can and use floating point numbers only when you have to. And you should always remember that floating point numbers have limited precision and comparing two floating point numbers to see if they are equal can give results you might not expect.

Comment: I find this a rather hand-wavy answer.  The question wasn't about representing fractions; it was about representing whole numbers.  Reasoning by analogy is weak; a _specific_ example where, in C#, integers will give you a more correct result than doubles would be more helpful.

Comment: @JoeStrout The answer isn't about fractions versus whole numbers, it's about exact representations (like 1/3) versus finite-precision representations (such as 0.33333333).

Comment: 1/3 and 0.3333333 are both fractions.  The question, it appears to me, isn't about representing such numbers; it's about representing whole numbers.  The question is simple: why do we need an "int" type when "double" can represent any integer just as well? Answers or examples involving non-whole numbers are irrelevant to the question.  Are there cases involving only whole numbers where, for example, comparisons might fail?

Comment: @JoeStrout There's nothing special about whole numbers versus fractions. 1 and 3/3 are the same. 323 and 3230/10 are the same. You encounter a problem when you have few digits of precision with whole nubmers just as you do with fraction. For example, with three digits of precision, 3234 and 3235 will both be represented the same, just as 1/3 and 0.333 would be represented the same with three digits of precision.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228360%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) the different types each have their own size.

For example, when working with big databases, an `int` or `float` may double up the required size.

Answer (score 2):

You have different datatypes because they use a different amount of bits to store data.

Typically an integer will use less memory than a double, that is why one doesn't just use the largest possible datatype.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_type

Answer (score 2):

Most of the answer given here deal directly with math concepts.  There are purely computational reasons for using integers.  several jump to mind:

1. loop counters, yes I know you can a decimal/double in the for loop but really do you need that degree of complexity?
2. internal enumeration values
3. array indices

Answer (score 1):

There are several reasons.  Performance, memory, even the desire to not see decimals (without having to play with format strings).

Answer (score 1):

[Floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point):

> In computing, floating point describes a method of representing an **approximation to real numbers** in a way that can support a wide range of values. Numbers are, in general, represented approximately to a fixed number of significant digits and scaled using an exponent.

[Integer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_%28computer_science%29):

> In computer science, an integer **is** a datum of integral data type, a data type which represents some finite subset of the mathematical integers.

So, precision is one argument.

Comment: Yes, but where, _in practice_, does this actually make a difference?

Comment: in radar software

Answer (score 1):

There are several reasons. First off, like people have already said, double stores 64-bit numeric values, while int only requires 32-bit.

Float is a different case. Both int and float store 32-bit numbers, but float is less precise. A float value is precise up to 7 digits, but beyond that it is just an approximation. If you have larger numbers, or if there is some case where you purposefully want to force only integer values with no fractional numbers, int is the way to go. If you don't care about loss of precision and want to allow a wider range of values, you can use float instead.

Answer (score 1):

The primary reason for using integers is memory consumption and performance.

1. doubles are in most cases stored in a 64b memory blocks (compared to 32b for int)and use a somewhat complicated standard for representation (in some cases approximation of the real values)
2. complicated representation that requires calculation of mantis and exponent.
3. in most cases it requires use of dedicated coprocessor for floating point arithmetic
4. for integers complements and shifting can be used in order to speed up the arithmetic operations.
5. a number of use cases where it is more appropriate (natural) to use integers like for indexing arrays, loops, for getting reminder of the division, counting etc.

Also if you would need to do all of this using types for representing real numbers your code would be more more error prone.