# Formatting data for saving and displaying in CakePHP 3.4

Tags: mysql, cakephp-3.0

I have a field in my table called **value**, it's an INT field of size 11 (MySQL). It stores data for money values, without the decimal and thousands separators. Ex.: 4.658,85 will become 465885 (brazilian number format).

Let's suppose I want to save the value 1,200.50:

I have an input field with a jQuery mask that will store this value in the format 1.200,50.

Then, in order to save it, I must do:

```
// In the Controller
        if ($this->request->is(['post'])) {
            // This will convert 1.200,50 to 120050
            $this->request->data['value'] = str_replace([',', '.'], '', $this->request->data['value']);

            $this->Entity->patchEntity($entity, $this->request->getData());

            if ($this->Entity->save($entity)) {
                // Entity saved...
            }
        }
```

After that, to show this value formatted in a View, I must do:

```
<!-- In a View -->
<p><?php echo number_format($data['value'] / 10, 2, ',', '.') ?></p>
```

When EDITING the Entity, I must also call the formatting function, because of the input with the jQuery Mask:

```
// When editing. In the Controller
        if ($this->request->is(['get'])) {
            if (!empty($entity['value'])) {
                $this->request->data['value'] = number_format($entity['value'] / 10, 2, ',', '.')
            }
        }
```

This works for my project, but I think there is a better and more professional way of doing such conversions before saving and before showing this value, it's a lot of work when I must call this field multiple times in the project. Can anyone, please, help me?

Comment: Why are you using `INT` in the first place, instead of something more appropriate like `DECIMAL`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13566038/why-should-i-use-integers-when-i-could-just-use-floats-or-doubles-in-c

Comment: How do you think that does apply to your situation? Where in your application do you _need_ to apply mathematical operations based on fractions and/or get exact integer results rather than rounded decimal ones? Given that `DECIMAL` is an [**exact-value fixed-point type**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fixed-point-types.html) with no unexpected rounding errors, it is very well suited for storing monetary data.

Comment: This might seem offtopic, but most of the time I see people using integers for storing monetary data, they do so because they just read somewhere to do so because floats are bad, and not because they actually require it and know what they're doing. CakePHP supports decimal types and even locale based input data parsing out of the box, so theoretically you could configure things so that you don't have to care about formatting the input at all.

Answer (score 0):

CakePHP have default number function, please use.

Example :

```
echo $this->Number->format('123456.7890', [
'places' => 2,
'before' => '¥ ',
'after' => ' !' ]);
// Output '¥ 123,456.79 !'
```

Reference link : https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/number.html#formatting-numbers

**Solution 1: Common function creation for concat first name & last name field using entity**

Example code :

**user entity file :**

```
class User extends Entity {

protected $_virtual = ['full_name'];

protected function _getFullName() {
    return $this->_properties['first_name'] . ' ' . $this->_properties['last_name'];
}}
```

**View file :**

```
<td><?= $input->full_name ?></td>
```

**Solution 2: We also possible to use beforeMarshal function**

```
public function beforeMarshal($data,$options) {
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        $data[$key] = number_format($value,2);
}}
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answers @ndm and @ananthaselvam-p, but even if I use the `DECIMAL` field, as suggested, and use the `NumberHelper`, I still face the same issue. For example: everytime I must call the `value` variable, I must use the Number format command. And, in the case I must call the variable inside the input, I would still must call a Helper inside a Controller and that's not a good practice. The point of the question is: Isn't any place I can configure that, any time this value is called in a view, it would appear formatted as I want?

Comment: You want to use common function for number format conversation?

Comment: you can possible to create the common function for number conversation using table entity "virtual field" create concept in cakephp3. i am update the answer. please check above, but that is simple example code.

Comment: Thanks  @Ananthaselvam, the `beforeMarshall` function worked when I want to convert the value **before** saving. The `_get<FieldName>` also works to format the field in the view wherever it's called, but there's a small problem that this function is also called when you use the `save` function in the controller

Comment: you have also to change validation